# Python Web Scraping - Save data in CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to save the data scraped from URLs such as "https://www.holidify.com/places/shimla/mall-road-shimla-sightseeing-3502.html". 
When saving the data in a csv file only the data from last url from the range gets saved in the csv file. 
I need that data from all of the URLs gets saved in the csv file.

```
pages = []
for i in range(1, 10, 1):
    url = "https://www.holidify.com/places/shimla/mall-road-shimla-sightseeing-350" + str(i) + '.html'
    pages.append(url)
    for item in pages:
        page = requests.get(item)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        Place = list(soup.find(class_="col-md-10 col-xs-10 nopadding"))[1].get_text()
        City = list(soup.find_all(class_="smallerText"))[1].get_text()
        State = list(soup.find_all(class_="smallerText"))[2].get_text()
        Country = list(soup.find_all(class_="smallerText"))[3].get_text()
        About = list(soup.find_all(class_="biggerTextOverview"))[0].get_text()
        more_About = list(soup.find_all(class_="objHeading smallerText"))[0].get_text()
        Weather = soup.find(class_="currentWeather").get_text()
        demo = pd.DataFrame({ "Place": Place, "City": City, "State": State, "Country": Country, "About": About,"More About Places": more_About}, index=[0])
        demo.to_csv('demo.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append data into that file

```
demo.to_csv('demo.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8', mode = 'a')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick help. Now the all data does get saved in the csv file but each time with the coloumn names being printed with each entry.

Comment: @benazir there is option in [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to skip headers. You will have to use it in all loops except first. So maybe you should write headers before all loops and then write always without headers. Or put all data in list/dict and save it only once after `for`loop.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Umair append the data into the data frame and place the command demo.to_csv('demo.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8') outside the loop.